# Polygon on Map doesn't show semi transparent color

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am working on Google map application in which I am plotting a polygon on map but it is not displaying polygon with semi transparent color as a fill color. Following is the code for it

```
int strokeColor = 0xffff0000;
int fillColor = 0x44ff0000;
Polygon polygon = map.addPolygon(new PolygonOptions()
                  .add(new LatLng(fences.get(northWestPoint).lat,
                  fences.get(northWestPoint).lng),
                  new LatLng(fences.get(northEastPoint).lat,
                  fences.get(northEastPoint).lng),
                  new LatLng(fences.get(southEastPoint).lat,
                  fences.get(southEastPoint).lng),
                  new LatLng(fences.get(southWestPoint).lat,
                  fences.get(southWestPoint).lng),
                  new LatLng(fences.get(northWestPoint).lat,
                  fences.get(northWestPoint).lng))
                  .strokeColor(strokeColor)
                  .strokeWidth(2)
                  .fillColor(fillColor));
```

This is the output when it renders map:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to be correct, maybe the problem is on the calling order?
In my code I do:

```
public PolygonOptions buildPolygonOptions() {
        return new PolygonOptions().fillColor(fillColor).strokeColor(strokeColor).strokeWidth(strokeWidth).zIndex(zIndex);
    }
```

I don't know if it is the real motivation (I should have no sense) but it worths a try. In addition, in order to do the tests use two different colors for fill and stroke, so you can better see where is one and where the other.

Comment: what if you set different stroke and fill color? I mean different color not different alpha, like blue and green?

Then try to set the color as Color.RED instead of using the full hex value

Comment: Even I tried that but it didn't work. It still filling with red color and not respecting alpha

Comment: what? if you set fill color to Color.GREEN and stroke to Color.BLUE it is still red?

Comment: No I used Black color for stroke and my alpha red color for the fill color. it filled it with red color excluding alpha value

Comment: @N Dorigatti That was my fault, I was calling it in a loop so it was drawing polygons more than one time. Thank for the help